# How to calculate the received power or SNR based on rssi value in the RxJanusFrameNtf?

Tags: janus, unetstack

When I send a Janus frame between two nodes, at the receiving side in **RxJanusFrameNtf** there is **rssi** value,
How to calculate the received power or the SNR using rssi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rssi` value is good for making signal strength comparisons between different nodes. The `rssi` value in typically given in dB, but with an arbitrary reference. You'd need a noise measurement in dB with the same reference to convert `rssi` to SNR -- something that is specific to the implementation of a modem or simulation model. For example, Subnero modems publish the noise value in the same units (but potentially a larger bandwidth) as `phy.noise`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply